# php location redirect and special chars

Tags: php, redirect, get, urlencode

Until now I was only reading but now I have my first question and hopefully someone can help me with it.

You perform a search by submit:

```
input: Lösung? Tösung& -> url: http://127.0.0.1/?search=Lösung%3F+Tösung%26
```

If you are not logged in, then I redirect (location header) the search with url_encode to login:

```
...login/return_url=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2F%3Fsearch%3DLösung%3F+Tösung%26amp%3B
```

I get 'wrong' results for $_GET['return_url']:

```
http://127.0.0.1/?search=Lösung? Tösung&amp;amp;
```

When logged in and after redirecting (not encoding the url again) I get:

```
url: http://127.0.0.1/?search=Lösung? Tösung&  -> input: Lösung? Tösung
```

Maybe I should redirect with encoding the url before? But I get an error (url not readable?)

```
header("Location: ".urlencode(url)."");
```

How can I achieve that after redirecting I still get the same results like in first url and not losing special characters like in example?

Maybe it is simple but until now I did not get the correct result and hope that you can help.

Comment: maybe one way is to extract the part ?search= and only encode Lösung? Tösung&, but how can i do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing i see is the wrong url is given.
The format of a $_GET[] in the URL should be

```
http:// domain.com/index.php?myvar=var&myfoo=foo
```

For the first var after your page you use a **'?'**
For every var after that you couple them with **'&'**

urlencode and urldecode fixes your problem with the chars.

```
$url= "http://www.mysite.com/index.php?search=location&option=europe";

$encoded = urlencode($url);
// result: http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Findex.php%3Fsearch%3Dlocation%26option%3Deurope 

$decoded = urldecode($encoded);
// result: http://www.mysite.com/index.php?search=location&option=europe
```

With your url:

```
$url= "http://127.0.0.1/?search=Lösung%3F+Tösung%26";
```

encoded:

```
http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2F%3Fsearch%3DL%C3%B6sung%253F%2BT%C3%B6sung%2526
```

decoded:

```
http://127.0.0.1/?search=Lösung%3F+Tösung%26
```

Comment: i see no difference. i do urlencode on searchsite and then decode on login, redirecting header('location'encodedurl) still gets an error.

Comment: ö in a url is no good. So you will have to encode the Ö and keep the ? and & as is. The final result should be: http://127.0.0.1/?search=L%F6sung?+T%F6sung&. Use that as the original string. THen Urlencode /decode to work with it. redirect should go to the original string with the Ö as %F6.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need [rawurlencode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)

Comment: hm at which point i should use it, maybe you can be a bit more specific?

Comment: It Encodes the given string according to RFC 3986, so I think not only characters like `?`, `=`, `#`, `[` and `]` will be encoded, but everything that is not a-zA-Z0-9_.

Comment: Ah ok but this does not work. Same result, missing charachters, redirecting rawurlencoded url gets also an error.

Comment: Hmmm, and maybe as you use query string, try [http_build_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to create the whole URL.