# Header redirect with special characters

Tags: php

I've been redirecting using a 301 `header`. However, when country-specific characters are used, they're for some reason encoded as UTF-8 characters which doesn't always work in a link. How do I get around this?

```
// Fetched from DB depending on situation
$redirect = "https://www.example.com/åäö";

// I want this to return https://www.example.com/åäö
header("Location: ".$redirect."",TRUE,301);
// But it actually returns https://www.example.com/%E5%E4%F6
```

I'm asking here because I've failed to find anything useful on this site. Thanks in advance.

Comment: always `urlencode()` anything going into the url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php location redirect and special chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590177/php-location-redirect-and-special-chars)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Probably right but that interferes with something else on the site (which I haven't touched for a long time and now know little about) and become https://mywebsite.se/https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%E5%E4%F6

Comment: Might just leave this one out, thanks though :D

Comment: @RiggsFolly Actually, `utf8_encode($redirect)` solved this particular problem. Probably a complete hack that's gonna cause more problems but that might do for now.

Comment: You must not encode the _whole_ URL, but only the individual parts of it. URL encoding the full `https://www.example.com/...` makes no sense here - because URL encoding means _remove_ the special meaning these characters might have in a URL. But you don't want to remove the meaning that stuff like `://` and the slash after the domain name have. Only the `åäö` should get URL encoding applied here.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
header("Location: ".urlencode($redirect));
```

You can use urldecode for the reverse operation